# Number of times a code is executed

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity

I have a piece of code that says:

for i = 4,16, . . . , n

I am trying to find an upper bound in terms of big oh notation for the number of times the statement gets executed. I believe here it goes like 4,4<sup>2</sup>,4<sup>3</sup> ... and so on. Since it grows exponentially, it looks like to me that that code is executed about O(logn) times. Am i right? Thanks in advance.

Comment: add a counter in your code and increment it, you'll have your answer right away

Comment: Without more information, this could also mean `i` is incremented by 12 in each step, which would give O(n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can confirm your result by thinking in terms of a loop whose index variable is used as the exponent, taking the values `1, 2, 3, ... , floor(log_4(n))`